# Ingress - Connection refused

Tags: express, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I know that they are tons of similar problem but after I have read all of them I am not able to figure it out... :/

**First of all I am not using minikube, I am using kubernetes docker desktop.**

I have simple express.js server like:

```
app.get('/test', async (_, res) => {
  console.log("Sth happened")
  res.json({ status: 200 });
});
```

**I am trying to deploy it and use ingress to expose it to my localhost.**

What I have done:
In etc/hosts I have added:

```
127.0.0.1 123test.mydomain.com
```

The ingress looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mytestservice
  namespace: mytestservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: 123test.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: mytestservice
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mytestservice
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    name: mytestservice
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mytestservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: mytestservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mytestservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mytestservice
          image: myimagename
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
              ...my envs, doesnt matter
```

**When I deploy it the pod is up and running because I am able to see startup logs**
The ingress description

```
kubectl get ingress mytestservice
NAME        CLASS    HOSTS                     ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
mytestservice   <none>   123test.mydomain.com             80, 443   53s

kubectl describe ingress mytestservice
Name:             mytestservice
Namespace:        mytestservice
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                     Path  Backends
  ----                     ----  --------
  123test.mydomain.com
                           /   mytestservice:80 (10.1.0.16:3000)
Annotations:               kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                           meta.helm.sh/release-name: mytestservice
                           meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: mytestservice
Events:                    <none>
```

When i CURL it I receive:

```
curl 123test.mydomain.com/test
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 123test.mydomain.com port 80: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is DNS. With your local /etc/hosts you are pointing to localhost instead to the IP of your Kubernetes host.

Comment: When I map it like myclusterip myingressdomain gives me timeout.

Comment: myingressdomain is of course 123test.mydomain.com

Comment: might it be the problem that when I hit kubectl get ingress there is no ADDRESS under this insgress?

Comment: Have you checked the port forwarding option? https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-desktop

Comment: @MateuszGebroski yes can be the case.

Comment: port forwarding was an option here, it works just for testing purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you create all the resources in the same namespace? I see your ingress is defined as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mytestservice
  namespace: mytestservice
```

so it will be created in the `mytestservice` namespace. Whereas your deployment and service doesn't have the `namespace: mytestservice` in metadata. So they will be created in the `default` namespace.

check if all your resources are in the same namespace:

```sh
kubectl get deployments --namespace mytestservice
kubectl get service --namespace mytestservice
kubectl get ingress --namespace mytestservice
```

a hint to the error is in the describe of the ingress:

```
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
```

Comment: Yes, they are present. I believe that I dont need default backend because by default, traffic sent to a ClusterIP or NodePort Service may be routed to any backend address for the Service and they are mapped to the pod which contains container mytestservice exposed on 3000

Comment: So basically ingress with 123test.mydomain.com is related to service which exposes port 80. This service is then mapped to port 3000 in pod which holds express server

Comment: I have followed @Michael Johann hints and it was solved. But... anyway thanks a ton, have a great day!